# jquery .animate by % of object X or Y

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, percentage

Due to some css limitations between IE and the rest of the world I am forced to use the .animate as a % rather than px or the objectToMove jumps (IE only) then animates.

So if the following is used

```
 $('.myClick').click(function() {
  $('.objectToMove').animate({
    top: '+=10%'
          }, 'fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

It will move the objectToMove by 10% of screen height. I would like to move it as 10% of the objectToMove height.

Is this possible without having to get the screen and object height and work out the % of the object to screen height etc?

**example**

canvas size = 720px

objectToMove = 100px

I want to move objectToMove by 10px not 72px

thx
Art

Comment: To clarify, lets say .objectToMove is 500px, are you trying to animate it 50px? (10% of object height)

Comment: @AaronMiler that is correct where the canvas size is say 720px objectToMove is 100px I would like to move the object 10px not 72px

Comment: could you get '+=' +($('.objectToMove').height() / 100)*10?

Comment: @AlexBall that did the trick, can you add as answer and I will mark as correct. Thx for the prompt reply, Art

Comment: @artvanderlay, I'm happy to be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple way,

with

```
top: '+=' + ( $('.objectToMove').height() / 100 ) * 10;
```

you can obtain the desired percentage height of the object

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have. If you are forced to continue to work in percentages this should work.

To start I'm going to get the hieght of the element, and the HTML.

```
var moveObject = $('.objectToMove').height();
var html = $('html').height();
```

Then I'm going to find out what moving the object 10% of it's own height would be

```
var distance = (moveObject/html)*10;
```

Now, I'm going to move the object 10% of it's height from the top.

```
$('.objectToMove').animate({
    top: '+='+distance+'%'},1500);
```

I tested this and it worked for me. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thx @AaronMiler, that is what I had long coded and does work, however in short form Alex's comment above works well. - Thx for the follow up, Art